# String column in Android SQLite DB being converted to exponential value

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a column in my SQLite table of type String. When I insert a string such as '600e2', it adds '60000'. Looks like it's taking the 'e' as exponent. Is this some known attribute of SQLite? Any API call that can be made to circumvent this?
Thanks,
Rajath

Comment: please change that columns data type to text and see what happend..

Comment: If I change to 'text', then it works. But can I do this on an update to the application?... since existing users have the db with 'String' type.

Comment: @Chirag - in any case, I might have to go with your solution. Thank you.... Also, I can't seem to mark your answer as correct

Comment: I add my answer then you can mark that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your that column datatype to text . So it can handle the exponent .

Yes,you can alter the column datatype on database update .

Answer (score 0):

Although you can specify the "type" of a SQLite column, you can store any type in any column. If you put a string into an integer it's ok, if you put a number into a string, it's also ok.

In my test here, if I wrap the string in quotes;
update table set column = '700e2';
then it stores as 700e2

If I do 
update table set column = 700e2;
then it comes back as 70000.

Comment: I'm using the following function [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) .. Here, if i use quotes, it is reflected in the value too.